# Получение номера первого видимого элемента

Tags: android, recyclerview

Переопределяю анимацию перемещения элементов в RecyclerView. Если view первое сверху необходимо производить другую анимацию. Как определить что view является первой на текущем экране? В самом списке при этом она может иметь любой номер.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У `LayoutManager`-ов есть метод [`findFirstVisibleItemPosition()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/LinearLayoutManager.html#findFirstVisibleItemPosition()), который вернет позицию в списке первого полностью видимого на экране айтема.

Comment: Как всё было просто. Спасибо